# как получить значение переменной, если значение будет присвоено не сразу?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, асинхронность

Приветствую!
Есть код на javascript:

```
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    var result;

    connection.query(sql_getData, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        result = rows;
    });

    console.log(result,"[<------------]");


    res.render("pages/index", {
        title: "Главная",
        msg: "Привет Мир!",
        data: result,
        info: ""
    }); 
});
```

Я использую тут express.js и пакет mysql.

Я проверил, соединение с базой работает корректно, данные я получаю.
Но вот в этом месте:

```
var result;

connection.query(sql_getData, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    result = rows;
    console.log(result,"[<--данные получены--]");
});

console.log(result,"[<--undefined--]");
```

в этом месте я не могу из анонимной функции вытащит данные.
Я предлагаю, что дело в том, что код исполняется сразу же, а запрос к базе и получение результата -- занимает определенное время и поэтому я вижу в консоли, неопределенное значение.

Как поступать в таких случаях?

Comment: Запускайте код, которому нужны данные из переменной result только после того, как они придут от сервера. После `result = rows;` можно оформить код или его вызов.

Comment: @silksofthesoul: А что, в ноду promise не завезли? С 4.0+ вроде [всё пучком](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#node4).

Comment: @Visman вы имеете ввиду, в connection.query(... , function(...){...result=rows; /*размещаем вызов нужного кода*/  console.log(result,"[<------------]");


    res.render("pages/index", {
        title: "Главная",
        msg: "Привет Мир!",
        data: result,
        info: ""
    });} --так? мне кажется это немного не красивым. если других путей нет решения этой проблемы, то вы можете оформить это ввиде ответа.

Comment: @romeo я только изучаю это.  не могли бы вы продемонстрировать пример?

Comment: @silksofthesoul: [Стандрат](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), статья [на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/) и известный полифил для nodejs - [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/features.html)

Comment: @romeo Спасибо большое:) я уже не много разобрался(в том числе и с промисами, благодаря вашей наводке.) и решил проблему(...пока не знаю, на сколько правильно...)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решается с помощью Promise,  как подсказывали в комментариях @Visman и @romeo

Я изучил примеры приложений на [githab](https://github.com/search?q=express%20example) и многое изменил в своем коде.

Примерное решение ситуаций, когда данные поступают с запаздыванием примерно так:

```
var getData = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject){
        connection.connect();
        connection.query(sql_showAll, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if(err){reject(err);throw err;}
            resolve(rows);
            // теперь когда сделаем присваивание в
            // случае успеха, получаем содержимое rows
        });
        connection.end();
    }
);
```

..я если честно до сих пор не очень понимаю как эта магия работает.
(сохраняется чувство, что я что то не так сделал. ...это вроде тот-же "фрукт", только "вид с боку".)

```
    app.get("/", function(req,res){
        // теперь можно сделать вот так
 getData 
    .then(
      function(result){
        res.render('todo', {
           title: 'Задачи'
          ,data: result
          ,trace_info: ">>><<<"
        });
      },function(err){console.log(err);}
    );
```

--UPD. решение не верное. полученные данные обновляться не будут, если БД изменится.

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно подсказали. Используйте promise или генераторы.

Насчет того,что не обновится,если обновится база - это вам никакой модуль делать не будет.Если база обновилась,то надо сделать новый запрос, других вариантов нет.